# How do I get my icon for grub customizer back?

Tags: kde, icons, launcher, plasma, installed-programs

I have the icon for 'grub customizer'. It is a .png and it is located in file:///var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-focal-universe/64x64/grub-customizer_grub-customizer.png. However in my app launcher it shows a different icon. It is like a black monitor. See the picture. [image]. So I clicked on the opties for filetype ( opties voor bestandstype ) and that shows the right picture. Is there another way to change the icon? I know it is only a minor thing, but I want it to be correct (if possible).

Also I tried uninstalling/purging and installing grub customizer again. Did not work though. I had the same problem with four-in-a-row, Kpatience, Kmines and Ksudoku. This method worked for them, but not for Grub Customizer.

Edit: I found the black icon. It is located in /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48. I cannot change it though. Kwikdisk said it was mounted, so I tried to unmount it in the terminal ( sudo umount /dev/loop15 ). It responded that the target was busy.

My running system is
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.15.5-051505-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB

in triple boot with Mint 20.2 Uma Cinnamon and Windows 10 on a HP  Envy.

Comment: @ Andra, thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that worked was located in `var/lib/app-info/ubuntu-focal-universe/48x48`. So now everything is as it should be.